# Where could my character have learnt Primordial?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, languages

I just created a DnD character. He speaks the languages Common, Elvish and Primordial.

Where could he have learned Primordial? He learned Elvish when he spent 2 years with the Elves.

Comment: As written, this question is wholly subject to player preference and realm-specific criteria. You could potentially ask for a list of things that speak primordial within a specific realm, but depending how the question is rephrased might result in it being flagged for too broad (a list of 10 things is feasible, 100 not so much).

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here. This site works best with questions that have a single objective "best" answer, whereas your question is essentially asking for opinions on how your character's backstory could justify their language choices. It's not a bad question, it's just a poor match for this site. Take a look [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/35259) to see a list of recommended forums where this particular question would be better suited. Do stick around and don't hesitate to ask any questions where you do need an objective answer...

Comment: If you are playing in an existing campaign settings, (e.g. Forgotten realms or similar) we may be able to answer this. [Edit] you question to include more details about your world. Otherwise this is too opinion based for the site.

Comment: @Piomicron: Please don't answer in comments. [See this related discussion.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)